# Get a non-uniform sample with numpy

Tags: numpy, random, sample, uniform

I would like to get a non-uniform sample (500 int) with numpy. I tried numpy.random.randint, but I get a uniform sample. Any simple solutions ?
Thanks for yours answers.

Comment: Which distribution should it follow?

Comment: Have a look at ‘numpy.random.randn’ to generate random numbers from a normal distribution: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of non-uniform distributions in [`scipy.stats`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html), and use them in such way:

```py
from scipy.stats import <distribution_you_want>

sample = <distribution_you_want>.rvs(size=500)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to generate samples from a distribution, staying in NumPy is probably easier.  (Scipy provides methods for the PDFs themselves, which can become more complicated.)  There are dozens of non-uniform distributions to choose from in the [`numpy.random`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.Generator) module.  For example, if you're after discrete, integer, nonnegative samples:

```py
sample = np.random.poisson(5, size=1000)
plt.hist(sample)
```

[image]